# Why do my devices appear to have symlinks , which are empty?

Tags: linux, mount

I am finding that I can't mount a device, sdb.

However, I don't see it in mounts:

```
[root@idh1 rhs-hadoop-install-0_61]# mount | grep --color dev
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw)
```

And I don't see any symlink mounts pointing to it:

```
[root@idh1 rhs-hadoop-install-0_61]# ls -altrh /dev/* | grep sd
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,  16 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,  17 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   0 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   2 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   1 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Feb  4 14:43 8:16 -> ../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:17 -> ../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Feb  4 14:43 8:0 -> ../sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:2 -> ../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:1 -> ../sda1
```

What are these magic "arrows" which point to `../sdb`? It appears maybe they are making sdb "busy", such that I can't format it.

Comment: [We've been here before](http://superuser.com/questions/709814/).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you're using a wildcard, together with what the grep command hides from you.

The shell expands the wildcard for you, so the `ls` sees the command as `ls /dev/autofs /dev/block /dev/bsg` and so on for every file and directory that you have in your `/dev/`. You can demonstrate what `ls` sees by doing `echo /dev/*` to just see how the shell expands the wildcard.

As a side effect of this, all files in all folders in `/dev/` are also listed. Since your `ls` command (after the shell has expanded the wildcard) contains a bunch of directories, each directory will have its own heading. So the actual output looks something like:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,  16 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,  17 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   0 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   2 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   1 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda1

...

/dev/block:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Feb  4 14:43 8:16 -> ../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:17 -> ../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Feb  4 14:43 8:0 -> ../sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:2 -> ../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:1 -> ../sda1
```

However, the `/dev/block` line is hidden by the `grep` command, so you don't see it. Try without the `grep` and maybe using `less` to see clearly what `ls` is outputting.

To confuse thing more, the `8:16` in `8:16 -> ../sdb` is a file name and not a timestamp or anything else. `/dev/block/8:16` is the name of a block device, which is symlinked to `../sdb`, or `/dev/sdb` as it were.

You can stop `ls` from expanding subdirectories by specifying the `d` flag.

```
ls -altrhd /dev/* | grep sd
```

Or of course, by not putting a wildcard after `/dev/`:

```
ls -altrh /dev/ | grep sd
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't want to mount `sdb` but the partition that is on the device, `sdb1`. That's why you can't mount it.

As for the magic arrows, they're not magic or arrows, the file name is actually the number after the time:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Feb  4 14:43 8:16 -> ../sdb
                                          ----
                                            |-> File name
```

The arrows themselves are standard notation for symbolic links. The general format is:

```
link_name -> /path/to/target
```

These are not actually in `/dev` but in `/dev/block` and are correctly pointing to `/dev/sdb` which is `../sdb` from `/dev/block` (`..` is the parent directory).  The reason they were listed is becayuse you ran `ls /dev/*` instead of `ls /dev/` so the contents of all subdirectories were also listed.

You can check all this by running:

```
$ ls -lath /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,  16 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,  17 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   0 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   2 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   1 Feb  4 14:43 /dev/sda1

$ ls -lath /dev/block/sd*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Feb  4 14:43 8:16 -> ../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:17 -> ../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    6 Feb  4 14:43 8:0 -> ../sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:2 -> ../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Feb  4 14:43 8:1 -> ../sda1
```

Comment: "You ran `ls` with the `-r`, recursive, flag." Incorrect. `-r` means reverse sort order. My answer explains why these files were actually listed.

Comment: @nitro2k01 Damn, my bad. I know, that's why I have the correct command in my answer. Brain short circuited there, thanks for pointing it out.